# Redirect causing double slashed urls (in Nextjs version 11)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a relative path in my code here:

//Nextjs config being imported to the react component

```
const domain = 'https://testsite.com'

let testUrl = `${domain}/images/logos/amt_logo.gif`;

let imageProps = {
src: {testUrl}
}
```

I have another website with some redirection code which is creating a double slash in the url as per below as you can see before `images`:

https://testsite.com/images/logos/amt_logo.gif --> https://www.testsite.com//images/logos/amt_logo.gif

How can I have some conditional code on my react page that goes: 'If page being redirected eliminate the second slash'?

Comment: You can use `url.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");` to remove extra `//` from the URL. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/X6jzs/

Comment: ah cool thanks @PsyGik I actually looked at that one but because I am unable to test in staging I was unsure if that would work. Will try that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vanilla JS [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor.

```js
const base = "https://testsite.com/"; // works with or without trailing slash
const path = "/images/logos/amt_logo.gif"; // works with or without leading slash
const { href } =  new URL(path, base);

const imageProps = {
    src: href
}
```